# Affine transformation in homogeneous coordinates: translation does not work, c#

Tags: c#, arrays, graphics2d

Good day.

There is the code below for drawing of square and transformation in homogeneous coordinates in c#.

Operations of scaling and rotation work properly (commented strings in body of code), but operation of translation does not work. It seems, last row on T-matrix (with coordinates [2,0],[2,1],[2,2]) does not affect on operation.

Could anybody see the mistake of code?
With regards, thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AFFINES02
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        double[,] Sq = new double[4,3];
        double[,] T = new double [3,3];

        private double RadianToDegree(double angle)
        {
            return Math.PI * angle / 180.0;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ResizeRedraw = true;
            Load += Form1_Load;
            Paint += Form1_Paint;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                       
            //Original matrix
            Sq[0, 0] = 0;
            Sq[0, 1] = 0;
            Sq[1, 0] = 50;
            Sq[1, 1] = 0;
            Sq[2, 0] = 50;
            Sq[2, 1] = 50;
            Sq[3, 0] = 0;
            Sq[3, 1] = 50;

            //Transformation matrix
            T[0, 0] = 1;
            T[0, 1] = 0;
            T[0, 2] = 0;
            T[1, 0] = 0;
            T[1, 1] = 1;
            T[1, 2] = 0;
            T[2, 0] = 2; //x-translation
            T[2, 1] = 2; //y-translation
            T[2, 2] = 1;

            //T[0, 0] = Math.Cos(RadianToDegree(90)); //0.707;                //T[0, 0] = 1;
            //T[0, 1] = Math.Sin(RadianToDegree(90));//0.707;                 //T[0, 1] = 0;
            //T[0, 2] = 0;                                    //T[0, 2] = 0;
            //T[1, 0] = -(Math.Sin(RadianToDegree(90)));//-0.707;             //T[1, 0] = 0;
            //T[1, 1] = Math.Cos(RadianToDegree(90));//0.707;                 //T[1, 1] = 1;
            //T[1, 2] = 0;                                    //T[1, 2] = 0;
            //T[2, 0] = 0;                                    //T[2, 0] = 0;
            //T[2, 1] = 0;                                    //T[2, 1] = 0;
            //T[2, 2] = 1;                                    //T[2, 2] = 1;




        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            double[] b = new double[3];//intermediate matrix
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)//cicle for 4 point of square
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    b[i] = 0;
                    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                        b[i] = b[i] + Sq[j, k] * T[k, i];
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                    Sq[j, k] = b[k];

            }

            Graphics gfx = e.Graphics;
            Pen skyBluePen = new Pen(Brushes.DeepSkyBlue);
            int cx = ClientSize.Width / 2;
            int cy = ClientSize.Height / 2;
            gfx.DrawLine(skyBluePen, cx, 0, cx, ClientSize.Height);
            gfx.DrawLine(skyBluePen, 0, cy, ClientSize.Width, cy);
            Pen SqPen = new Pen(Brushes.BlueViolet);
            gfx.DrawLine(SqPen, (int)(cx + Sq[0, 0]), (int)(cy - Sq[0, 1]),
            (int)(cx + Sq[1, 0]), (int)(cy - Sq[1, 1]));
            gfx.DrawLine(SqPen, (int)(cx + Sq[1, 0]), (int)(cy - Sq[1, 1]),
            (int)(cx + Sq[2, 0]), (int)(cy - Sq[2, 1]));
            gfx.DrawLine(SqPen, (int)(cx + Sq[2, 0]), (int)(cy - Sq[2, 1]),
            (int)(cx + Sq[3, 0]), (int)(cy - Sq[3, 1]));
            gfx.DrawLine(SqPen, (int)(cx + Sq[3, 0]), (int)(cy - Sq[3, 1]),
            (int)(cx + Sq[0, 0]), (int)(cy - Sq[0, 1]));           
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't code this myself but use [System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix(v=vs.110).aspx#Konstruktoren) instead. Are you sure, your matrix multiplication is correct? Try testing that one separately first. Why does Sq need to be of size 4x3? Also, you might easily get confused about rows and columns in the matrix. Have you tried using T[0, 2] and T[1, 2] instead?